# Non-parametric two-way ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova

I have found out that my data does not meet the assumption of homonogeneity of variance. I was going to use the two-way ANOVA code before I found this out:

```
summary(aov(Length.M~Species*Site,data=x.r))
```

Is there an R code that provides non-parametric equivalent of a two-way ANOVA similar to the one above?

Comment: If you don't even know what statistical method to you, your question probably belongs on [stats.se]. They already seem to have a [relevant thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18073/general-approach-for-non-parametric-two-way-anova). Determining which method is right for your data is not on-topic for this site.

Comment: I think the Friedman test (`?friedman.test`) is probably close to what you want, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test . Depending on what you're trying to do, transforming the data might help too.  (`library("MASS"); ?boxcox`).  But I agree that CrossValidated might be better.